# In Objective-c What happens if a parent deallocs a child, while a child method is executing?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, release, dealloc

I have a parent who has a strong reference to a child. The child has a weak reference to the parent.

The parent calls methods on the child on one thread. It is possible that the parent could dealloc the child before the child method finishes executing.  There isn't an apparent way to synchronize this to avoid the parent deallocing the child till the method returns.

What will happen?

EDIT: I'm not using ARC, and this will run on iOS 3.1.2

EDIT: What about using [NSValue valueWithNonretainedObject] ?

According to this:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Articles/gcAPI.html

The reference is set to nil when the object is garbage collected. But since iOS doesn't have garbage collection, will it have a dangling pointer?

EDIT: Found this useful post, so I thought i would share it with others learning about this topic too:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/rules-to-avoid-retain-cycles.html

Answer (score 3):

If you are using something like:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: selctor target: theChildObject withObject: nil];
```

you have no issue.  The target is retained (and the object if supplied) until the thread has completed execution.  If not, you need to arrange proper synchronization e.g. have an atomic accessor for the child in the parent.

```
// in the parent interface

@property (retain) id child; // Note no nonatomic

// in the child thread 

id myChild = [parent child];  // myChild will be autoreleased in the current thread if the child property is atomic
if (myChild != nil)
{
    [myChild retain];             // not strictly necessary as long as the current autorelease pool is not drained 
    // do the stuff you need with myChild
    [myChild release];
}
```

Comment: Note that the same holds true of `dispatch_async()`; it'll retain any objects in the dispatched blocks for the duration of the block's execution.

Comment: So if we use non-atomic, the child will either be nil, or it will be retained till the end of the thread? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I may not be able to use this - all the children are stored in an NSMutableArray. I can change the property for the array to by atomic, but how does that affect the children since they are stored in the array?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a well designed code, you need to avoid this problem to begin with. For example only release the parent when all its children's work are complete, or put the release code in a completion handler block that will only be called when no child method is being executed.

The quick fix however is what babbidi said, or this if you're using ARC: retain a strong reference to the parent in a local variable, say `localParent`, at the beginning of the method. This creates a retain cycle and therefore neither of the objects will not be released. Since `localParent` is local, it's automatically released at the end of the method, breaking the retain cycle and allowing both objects to be freed.

If your method has return value, use the local parent in an async block to effectively simulate autorelease behaviour:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [localParent self]; // this does nothing
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think perhaps my design should avoid weak references altogether. But at this time I have not been able to "crash" my application, as it seems that the thread scheduler effectively stops all threads in the right order. But this needs to be verified, as it is third party code, and it is possible that all threads coincidentally just manage to finish executing before the dealloc starts.

Answer (score -2):

***The following does not apply to ARC*** (in case you're talking about ARC)

It will probably crash. You can however call `[self retain];` when one method starts, and `[self release];` before it finishes executing the method (before return or before the end of the method). The parent would call `release` on the child, but this has been retained (if the method is executing), so retainCount should still be > 0 (when dealloc is called).

If the method uses the weak reference to parent, then, when dealloced, the parent should call `child.parent = nil;`, to prevent the child of accessing its released memory.

Comment: This sounds like really good advice. I would like to hear other peoples views about this too, as I am not very experienced.

Comment: What does the child return to if the parent deallocs? If the parent is calling a method on a child that returns a value, and the parent deallocs before the child returns, where does the return value go? Does it crash? I guess the solution to this is to retain and release the parent within the method too?

Comment: If a method is called (synchronously) from the parent, then the return value will go to the parent, since the child method was called from a parent method, which waits for the return value (unless `oneway void`). If the method is called asynchronously, then the child would probably call `[parent callbackMethod];` when the method is done, but since `parent` is set to nil (parent calls `child.parent = nil;` when dealloced), nothing will happen. As @Mo. mentioned, if possible, it's better to cancel or wait until the children stop their execution before dealloccing)

Comment: -1 This is no good.  The parent could call release on the child and have it deallocated between the child method starting and the call to `[self retain]` actually incrementing the reference count.  You need proper synchronization

Comment: @JeremyP I agree that the solution doesn't cover all situations, but I usually find this useful with asynchronous calls, where the method is called from the main thread, and it then launches a new thread where it executes. Anyway.. I haven't thought it through in case child method is called from different thread.

Comment: To expand on what @JeremyP said;  retain/releases should be managed on a per thread basis.  When an object is "passed" from one thread to another, it should be retained on the first thread and released on the second (or there should be a synchronization primitive that enforces this).  To do otherwise is to incur difficult to debug race conditions.

Comment: I'm don't understand what you mean by passing the object between threads. In this relationship we have parent with strong reference to child, child with weak reference to parent. Child methods are directly called by the parent, & parent properties are modified by the child methods. It doesn't make sense for one thread to retain and the other to release.one thread should do both or non at all, and when releasing stop the other thread, Because if one thread retains and the other releases , both threads would need to be in sync to avoid overreleasing. Can you elaborate what you mean? Thanks.